# execute sql DDL WITH ibscript at runtime

Tags: firebird, delphi-2010, isqlquery

I have a problem about running script

```
IBScript := TIBScript.Create(nil);
IBScript.Database := FDM_DB.IBD_GCV;
IBScript.Transaction := FDM_DB.IBT_GCV;
IBScript.Terminator := ';';
IBScript.AutoDDL:=true;
IBScript.Script.Clear;
IBScript.Script.Add('GRANT INSERT, UPDATE ON ' + table_name + '  TO ' + user + ' ;');
IBScript.ExecuteScript;
IBScript.Transaction.CommitRetaining;
```

> strong textit shows me this message
>
> 'Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -104 Token unknown - line 1,
>   column 43 TO'.

thank you in advance

Comment: What is the resulting SQL string? I suggest you construct it separately and log or print it.

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
GRANT INSERT, UPDATE ON ' + table_name + ' TO ' + user + ;
```

sql only.

So, check `'table_name'` variable value.
This error can occur when:

`table_name = '';//(empty string)`.

Comment: non i have correct value by debug thenx ' GRANT INSERT, UPDATE ON RECEPTION  TO KOVAROV; '

Comment: I tested with `table_name := 'RECEPTION'`. Works well.

Comment: in both cases works, but I get the error message after IBScript.Transaction.CommitRetaining;

Comment: thank you this other error sql in code from revoke before  this code